# JavaScript array delete Special

Tags: javascript

I have an array like:

```
var abc = ["a","b","c"];
```

And the indexes are 0,1,2

Suppose, I want to delete the 2nd item "b" and I the indexes swipe!

Out put:

```
abc = ["a","c"]
```

and the indexes are 0,1

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are the indexes always 0, 1, and 2?

Comment: yes, always starts from 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) function :

```
abc.splice(1,1) // from index 1, removes 1 element
```

Be careful that this changes the original array.

Comment: No problem, can you bit explain the parameters?

Comment: I linked to the complete documentation. But here the first argument is the position and the second one the number of elements to remove.

Comment: +1 but would prefer wording the other way around (`from index 1, removes 1 element`)

Comment: @PaulS. Good idea. I edited (you could have to).

Comment: @dystroy Yes, but I would feel `This edit is too minor; [...] edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post.` If you want to offer a way to do the same without modifying the original array, you could also add `var ac = abc.slice().splice(1, 1);` after your warning. (This time I'd feel the change too radical)

Comment: @PaulS. I just [had a look](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1615483/paul-s?tab=activity). I'm not surprised to see you don't edit too much I see. But in this precise case I don't feel the need for the cloning addition, as *"I like concise, easy-to-read questions and answers"* :p

Answer (score 0):

Use `splice()`. E.g:

```
abc.splice(1, 1);
```

would perform what you wanted in your example. `abc[1]` would now be `"c"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array splice `abc.splice(1,1);`

Details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on it... I think this is what you want...

```
var arr = ["a","b","c"];

arr.splice(1,1);

alert("["+arr.indexOf('a')+","+arr.indexOf('c')+"]");
```